# Why this constructor is being called?

Tags: c++

I'm confused about following program about why it calls first constructor.

```
class A  
{  
public:  
        A(const char *c="\0")  
        {  
                cout<<"Constructor without arg";  
        }  
        A(string c)  
        {  
                cout<<"New one";  
        }  

};  

int main()  
{  
        A a="AMD";  
        return 0;  
}
```

Output is 
`Constructor without arg`

Comment: Why do you have two constructors that essentially do the same thing (accept a string as a parameter)? Have the caller either convert the parameter to a C or C++ string so that you only need one constructor here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"AMD"` is a `const char[]`, which is implicitly converted to `const char*`, so the first constructor [`A(const char *c="\0")`]is the best match.

Note that `A(const char *c="\0")` is not a *constructor without an argument*, it's a constructor which takes a single `const char*` as an argument, and has an optional default value to use when a `const char*` isn't specified.  In this case, you're passing a `const char*`, so it uses it.

Comment: Wait, so `A a="AMD"` is the same as `A a("AMD")`?

Comment: @Derek Yes, initialization is not assignment.

Comment: @pmr Thanks, I have never seen anyone use that syntax.

Comment: @Derek It's an odd way to write it, but it will still call that constructor.

Comment: @Derek: They are quite similar, although not exactly equivalent. `A a="AMD";` requires that the constructor that takes a `const char*` must be accessible and not `explicit` and that the copy constructor is accesible. It is equivalent to: `A a(A("AMD"))` with the exception that the internal constructor `A("AMD")` must not be explicit. Additionally the compiler will in 99% percent of the cases elide the extra copy and will generate code equivalent to `A a("AMD");` **granted** that all the requirements above are met.

Answer (score 1):

Because a string literal is of type `const char[]` which implicitly converts to `const char*` which is preferred over the user-defined conversion `std::string(const char*)` (This is not really the signature of the `string` constructor, but enough for this explanation).

Also: initialization is not assignment. This is why a constructor and not `operator=` is called in the first place.

The preferred syntax for assignment in C++11 would be `A a{"ASDF"};`. It makes things more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the constructor with a const char * because that is what "AMD" is. It's not a string. If you put A a(string("AMD")) it will work.